# PySpark: How to read all json files where the key value pair in the json file is lets say for example: {"LOB": "Auto"}

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read all the json files in a path in to spark dataframe. only when the key value pair in json file is {"LOB": "Auto"}

Comment: You will have to read all the json files, create a dataframe. Then filter the dataframe based on the key-value pair. There is no look inside the file and then only read function in Spark.

Comment: @user238607 thank you for the comment. There are five different json files coming into the folder. they have different structure. So wanted to look inside and process the file. for example: LOB = Auto has different fields and LOB = HOME has different fields.